# recibir string de un json y convertirlo a object o array (php - java)

Tags: php, java, mysql

Buenas 
Es mi primer post y es sencillamente por que no se que mas hacer :c 
El tema es que tengo un web services donde realizo una consulta a una base de datos desde php y recibo un json del tipo String algo como esto.

```
[{"id":"1","usuario":"admin","clave":"admin","nombre":"Juan","apellido":"Sepulveda","edad":"25"}][{"id":"2","usuario":"user","clave":"123456","nombre":"Jose","apellido":"Gonzalez","edad":"34"}][{"id":"3","usuario":"rowso","clave":"rowso","nombre":"Juanito","apellido":"Sepulveda","edad":"25"}][{"id":"4","usuario":"nuevo","clave":"123","nombre":"nuevo","apellido":"yourmeh","edad":"58"}][{"id":"5","usuario":"","clave":"","nombre":"","apellido":"","edad":"0"}]
```

Necesito poder parsear esos datos obtenidos para poder usarlos libremente por ejemplo.

obtener usuario : admin para asignarlo alguna variable.

No se como hacerlo si traspasarlo a un arreglo y luego tomarlos 1 a uno o algo asi.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Intenta resolve como pienses que es correcto, si tienes algun problema al hacerlo entonces publicas una pregunta indicando de forma detallada cual es el error ademas de mostrar tu codigo, en ese momento nosotros trataremos de ayudarte con sugerencias o posibles soluciones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

como primera observación, el string que muestras como JSON no corresponde a una cadena que se pueda interpretar como un objeto,  no tiene las comas que definen cada elemento. Debes resolver esto primero.
Te recomiendo https://jsonlint.com/ para validar el string que quieres formatear.

Una vez dicho esto, en php el modo de convertir un json a arreglo u objeto es [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Una vez convertido a un tipo de dato iterable puedes acceder a los datos "libremente" como lo mencionas.

Un ejemplo pequeño donde se recorre el arreglo y se imprimen los usuarios:

```
    $var = '[{"id":"1","usuario":"admin","clave":"admin","nombre":"Juan","apellido":"Sepulveda","edad":"25"},{"id":"2","usuario":"user","clave":"123456","nombre":"Jose","apellido":"Gonzalez","edad":"34"},{"id":"3","usuario":"rowso","clave":"rowso","nombre":"Juanito","apellido":"Sepulveda","edad":"25"},{"id":"4","usuario":"nuevo","clave":"123","nombre":"nuevo","apellido":"yourmeh","edad":"58"},{"id":"5","usuario":"","clave":"","nombre":"","apellido":"","edad":"0"}]
';
$arr = json_decode($var, true);

foreach($arr as $k=> $v)
{
    echo "usuario ".$k.": ".$v['usuario']."<br>";
}
```

Saludos.

Comment: Paula
ya logro obtener los datos, gracias. El tema ahora es que no logro recorrer el json recibido solo me toma el primer dato, los otros no los obtiene.

este es mi codigo en php 
`$consulta = "SELECT * FROM usuario";

if($resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $consulta))
{
    while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_object($resultado))
    {
  $json_array = json_encode($fila);
  echo $json_array;
    }
}`

Comment: has intentado usar  [mysqli_fetch_all](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) en vez de  mysqli_fetch_object ??  ¿Es necesario trabajar los datos como json?

Comment: Ya lo solucione Paula valide el json en la web que me diste, tuve que guardarlo en un array en el php.
if($resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $consulta))
$array = array();
{
    while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($resultado))
    {
        $array[] = $fila;
    }
    print json_encode($array); 
}
 y luego desde el jsonArray - pasarlo a json object y en un ciclo los llamaba a todos <3 ! Gracias por tu ayuda